# For-Next Loop Dilemma

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, for-loop

Net Gurus;
I am trying to change the limit of a "For-Next" from within the "For-Next";
Is this possible at all; if not is there an alternative in VB.Net;
I am posting my VB.Net code below to explain exactly where am I;
Basically; I want to change the limit of "Check" to a value of 100 after performing some equations; if the user put > 100 in TextBox1. I JUST SIMPLIFIED THE CODE AS I HAVE SOME EQUATIONS WITHIN THE "For-Next" TO DETERMINE THE VALUE OF "Check":

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Check = 1
    Dim NumberofLoops = 3
    TextBox1.Text = 1
    For Check = 1 To NumberofLoops
        ' some equations
        If TextBox1.Text > 100 Then NumberofLoops = 100
        MessageBox.Show("Check = " & Check)
    Next
    Label1.Text = Check
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Do you really need to do  it inside of loop?

Comment: YES; that is why I called it "Dilemma"!

Comment: Try using a For loop. Not For/Next.

Comment: that has to work, did you already tried it? but as @YuriyGalanter mention, I dont think that is necesary. maybe you algorithm is not correct

Comment: @bto.rdz: VB for loop ending conditions are only evaluated on initial entry to the loop, unlike in C#/Java/C++/etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really need to change loop parameters inside of loop then FOR/NEXT is not going to work. You need to use [DO/LOOP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eked04a7.aspx) alternative. E.g.

```
Dim NumberofLoops = 3
Dim Check = 1

Do While Check <= NumberofLoops 
  If TextBox1.Text > 100 Then NumberofLoops = 100
  Check += 1
Loop
```

Comment: Yuriy you deserve the Title "VB.Net Guru"; I accepted your Answer and +1 for you...

Comment: No problem :) glad the solution was helpfull